# red lines in R pairs function

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am wondering what the red lines in R pairs function are.

`pairs(USJudgeRatings, lower.panel = panel.smooth, upper.panel = panel.cor)`

[image: R pairs function]

What I am actually looking for is a way to control these lines in the plot of scatterplots so that they represent some sort of quantiles/means. Basically the line plots should  first bin X and Y datasets then  pass lines through the means/quantiles of the bins and overlay on the scatter plots. Is this possible through an R function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: `?panel.smooth`

`pairs` uses `lowess` for computing [local regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression).